# NN converges quickly but is it a problem when performance is good on test set?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I have an LSTM model I'm using for time series predictions. In training it converges already after 3 epochs. The model performs quite well on the test data, but should I still be concerned about the fast convergence or should performance on test set be the overruling factor to decide if a model is good or not?

There is plenty of data points(100k) and two hidden layers with 124 and 64 nodes, so I don't think the model lacks complexity or data

Answer (score 0):

One problem you may be facing is a data leak, that is, that part of your test data is also on your training data and, therefore, the model will perform worse when used on actually unseen data.

A typical cause of this is to apply data augmentation or oversampling before splitting the data into train and test sets.

Answer (score 0):

If the model trains quickly and performs well on hold-out data, the problem could be easy to learn. Some problems are easy for a LSTM.